# How to find total number of nodes on which hadoop is installed

Tags: hadoop

How do I find out how many active nodes there are cuurently? I don't have admin rights to the cluster.

Comment: You can run `hdfs dfsadmin -report`. You have to have dfs admin privilege to run it. To get the namenodes you can run `hdfs getconf -namenodes`.

Comment: I tried this. This only gives the configured capacity, used capacity remaining capacity of dfs. Not the number of nodes.

Comment: It gives the number of nodes when you run it with dfs admin privilege. Try running it as user hdfs.

Comment: It gives me everything including a summary `Datanodes available: 8 (8 total, 0 dead)`.

Comment: `root` does not have `Superuser privilege` thus running it as `root` will yield at the bottom with this error `report: Access denied for user root. Superuser privilege is required`.

Comment: I am getting the Access Denied error at the bottem when I try to run it as admin although I am getting information on capacity. Also, did you mean run it as hdfs dfsuser -report ? I tried that. It says Error: Could not find or load main class dfsuser.

Comment: I am running it on root. Where exactly should I run it then?

Comment: You need to run it as the hdfs owner. In my case the hdfs owner is hdfs. `hdfs dfsadmin -report` is the same as `hadoop dfsadmin -report`. I didn't say `hdfs dfsuser -report`.

Comment: Ya. I guess I'll have to ask the admin/owner as I am not the owner. Thanks for your support @alvits !

Comment: use the following command: 
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs

Answer (score 8):

```
 hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

The above command will give you active and dead nodes. 
Even the namanode web UI 50070 will also give you the count of datanodes live or dead

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but this lists the HDFS nodes doesn't it? which is not necessarily the same as the number of worker machines doing the computation

Comment: so I think `yarn node -list -all` is closer to what the OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

You can find with this code in terminal:

```
yarn node -list -all
```

And you can see details of nodes (**Node-Id,Node-State,Node-Http-Address,Number-of-Running-Containers**)